# httpd - Redirect all 404 to specific page

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

I want to redirect visitors who go to pages that don't exist on my httpd server.

Lets say http://www.foo.com/wXGoL14445093-BgKb76/SNxM53-FxhsH.html (this page does not exist).

Once we go there we get the error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /wXGoL14445093-BgKb76/SNxM53-FxhsH.html was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at www.foo.com Port 80
```

How can I redirect all visitors who get that error to `www.foo.com` (home page)

Comment: Take a look at: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using `ErrorDocument` directive in Apache (since you are using apache)

1. Create an HTML page anywhere in your document root

`</html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; ,URL=http://foo.com">
    </head>
     <body> Page not found ...Redirecting to home page in 5 seconds...</body>
  </html>`

2. Out this HTML in your document root as say,  `four0four.html`
3. In your apache conf file add this line

`ErrorDocument 404 /four0four.html`

4. Restart Apache.

Now whenever you load an unknown page, apache will load the `four0four.html` for you. Within this HTML you have specified the refresh tag to refresh the page and go to your server in 5 seconds. You can change the `5` to any duration you want